# Select only the middle using nth(child, of-type,)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, match

I’m trying to match some elements from my table using nth-child or nth-of-type or every kind of “nth” but I’m stuck targeting elements from the middle selected on picture below in color green, can someone give me a idea how to do that, I don’t want to repeat an interval just want to select that section.  I don't want to use javascript or jQuery for this.

[image]

**[small fide example:](https://jsfiddle.net/y96oho8t/2/)**

```
.row:nth-child(n+4) .cell:nth-child(n+4) {
    background: green;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is this a fixed grid?  You will need more than one rule.

Comment: If you're selecting one, non-repeating section, why not use a class?

Comment: I understand you need a "middle child pseudo-class". I don't think this is possible just with css. I think you can use js to select the middle row from the table (and the rows before and after), then the middle cells in the rows.

Comment: @Paulie it is not fixed

Comment: @Michael_B all content will be dynamic so cannot use classes.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina actually is working, I find myself the solution :)

Comment: @RulerNature This is working for 10 rows, 10 columns, not for n rows and n columns.

Comment: @Madalina Taina it doesn't matter if there are 10 or 9 or whatever, the mechanism is the same.  In my example I was searching for an nth interval that could be targeted addressing to the corresponding row interval (from 4’th row till 6’th row) ".row:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6)" and after that to the corresponding cell interval (between defined row interval  target all cells from 4’th till the 6’th for all 3 rows )".cell:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6)" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer of my problem, I have solved myself  !

```
.row:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6) .cell:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6){
    background:red;
}
```